# Change NTLM hash in memory on the lock screen?

Tags: authentication, hash, windows

Is there a way to change the ntlm hash in memory to bypass Windows login?
For example, I have the NTLM hash of a Windows machine and I have physical access. Is possible to write the NTLM hash in memory and bypass the login or the unique way is crack the hash for get the password in plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the NT hash, you can just use it in a pass-the-hash attack to gain access to the system. I'm not aware of a way to execute this from a login screen.

If you've got physical access, you can always just boot to a live CD and reset the password that way.